# $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\int\limits_{E_k}f(x)dx=0$ implies $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}m(E_k)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be a Lebesgue measurable function on $[0,1]$ with $f(x)>0$ almost everywhere
Suppose that $\{E_k\}_k$ is a sequence of Lebesgue measurable sets in $[0,1]$ such that $$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\int\limits_{E_k}f(x)dx=0$$
Show that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}m(E_k)=0$

**My Observatioins:**
Let $A_n=\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n E_k$
Then $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a  countable collection of increasing measurable subsets. And $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} E_k=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$

Also as $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an increasing sequence of sets, we have $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_{A_n}f(x)dx=\int\limits_{\bigcup A_n}f$$

Moreover separately we have

$\begin{align}
m(\bigcup E_n)&= m(\bigcup A_n)\\&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}m(A_n)\\&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}m(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n E_k)\\
\end{align}$

But I cannot see how to use these details to arrive at the final answer.
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B_n=\{x\mid f(x)>1/n\}$. Then each $B_n$ is a measurable set and $B=\cup B_n$ has measure 1 by the assumption. Now the measure of $E_k\cap B_n$ goes to $0$ as $k\to \infty$ for every $n$. So
$$\lim_{k\to \infty} m(E_k\cap B)=\lim_{k\to \infty} m(E_k)=0.$$

Comment: How does $m(E_k\cap B_n)\to 0$ imply $m(E_k\cap B)\to 0$? I think you are missing a quick step.

Comment: $B$ is an increasing union of $B_n$.

Comment: @JCAA I mean, you seem to be doing $\lim_{k\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty} m(E_k\cap B_n)$, but up to this point you only have only shown that $\lim_{k\to\infty} m(E_k\cap B_n) = 0$

Comment: @JCAA Thank you for the comment. But can you please also explain why $E_k\cap B_n$ goes to $0$ when $k\to\infty$

Comment: @gune: That is because $\int_{E_k\cap B_n} f>1/n m(E_k\cap B_n)$

Comment: For all integers $N$ we have $m(E_k\cap \bigcup^N_{n=1} B_n)\le \sum_{n=1}^N m(E_k\cap B_n)$ so $m(E_k\cap \bigcup^N_{n=1} B_n)\overset{k}{\rightarrow} 0$.  If $\lim_km(E_k\cap \bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1} B_n)\neq 0$ then $m(E_{k_j}\cap \bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1} B_n)=\delta>0$ for some subsequence. Now choose $N$ so large that $m(B)-m(B_N)<\delta/2$, ok because the measures are finite. Then,  $m(E_{k_j}\cap \bigcup^{N}_{n=1} B_n)>\delta/2$ for all $j$. Contradiction.

Comment: @Matematleta: That is correct except for arguing that this $N$ exists, you need $\lim m(B_n)=m(B)$ which is true because $\cup B_n$ is an increasing union.

Comment: @JCAA right thanks! I did not think I had to repeat what was already pointed out in the previous comments.

Comment: Thank you every one!